# Part of speech of "that"?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, pronouns, parts-of-speech

In this sentence:

> Its shape resembles that of a kangaroo’s hind foot.

What part of speech would *that* be?

Comment: Why is this community?

Comment: In this case, _that_ means 'the shape', as in _Its shape resembles the shape of a kangaroo's hind foot._ Demonstratives, like any other pronoun, often refer to an entire noun phrase. The problem here is distinguishing the pronoun _that_ from the complementizer _that_. Luckily, this _that_ is modified by a prepositional phrase, so it pretty much hasta be a noun phrase.

Comment: What part of speech would what be?  ;)

Comment: In what sentence? Like _that_ -- and all other grammar words -- _what_ has a number or uses.

Answer (score 1):

Here "that" stands for "the shape" (of a kangaroo's hind foot).  Here the demonstratve adjective is used as a pronoun (without a following noun) and it has the sense of a determinative pronoun.  English has no special words for determinatives, it uses as substitute the demonstratives or that which /what,  the one who, people who, anyone who, he who, they who, whoever, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

In that sentence, *that* would be a relative pronoun.